# Injecting the TaskScheduler with Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to inject the `TaskScheduler` instance created by Spring?

I would like to schedule tasks programatically and for that, I guess I need to access the `TaskScheduler` but for some reason, it's not found by Spring for autowiring.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MySpringConfig {

}

@Component
public class MyClass implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MySpringConfig {

 @Bean
 public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
     //org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
     return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
 }
}
```

You can choose which ever implementation you like. ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is the simpler one as mentioned in this link.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler-implementations

Comment: plz, can you accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Worked wonders for me. Just autowire TaskScheduler and you are good to go.